# Implementing pre-populated sqlite database in phonegap using sqlite plugin

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, sqlite

I am currently using phonegap in android. I want to use my existing database using sqlite plugin. Since i am a newbie, i have read various numeral blogs and posts about the same but found nothing good. Can anyone please explain how to use sqlite plugin in phonegap android app.

It will be beneficial if you can explain in steps as i have not much knowledge using databases.

Articles that i have read: 
http://hansjar.blogspot.in/2013/04/how-to-easily-add-prepopulated-sqlite.html
http://gauravstomar.blogspot.ca/2011/08/prepopulate-sqlite-in-phonegap.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+GauravSTomarBootstrappingIntelligence+(Gaurav+S+Tomar+:+Bootstrapping+Intelligence