# how to populate a SQLite database and use that database in phonegap?

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, cordova, phonegap-plugins

so I'm new in Phonegap and I want to populate a database and use that database in my code. I want to know how can I do that but I don't know witch tool to use for populate a Sqlite database and how to open that database in my code.
I've seen the [sqlitePlugin](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.triarc.sqliteplugin) and [ioliteHelpers plugin](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/io.litehelpers.cordova.sqlite) but because of very short document I don't know how to use them exactly.
besides i have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021036/implementing-pre-populated-sqlite-database-in-phonegap-using-sqlite-plugin) too, but it don't have answers.
thanks in advance.

Comment: this link useful for you:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27187826/websql-for-phonegap-application/27189861#27189861

Comment: 2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26629244/phonegap3-4-0-android-app-with-sqlite-its-working-fine-in-emulator-but-not-in?noredirect=1#comment41867305_26629244

Comment: @Ved so I've done what you said in those questions but still no luck. I dont know what is 00000000000001.sqlite file and i am using intellij.

Comment: 00000000000001.sqlite is sqlite db file.

Comment: come on man i know that much if i didn't how would i know what is mydb.sqlite but i want to know where is it. how can i find it. why would i need that?

Comment: Here mydb.sqlite is prepopulated sqlite database file name. If you are working with Andriod, then you should put it in to bundle of app that is assets folder. If you are usin iOS you should drag the mydb file to Resource directory in Xcode by choosing the option “Create groups for any added folder” and check the “Copy items into destination group’s folder (if needed)” option while adding reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though this question is old... thought it might help someone to post my solution - found in 2017. (Since PhoneGap has changed, older solutions may no longer work or be accepted on the Android and Apple app markets.) I worked on this problem for a long time - the issue about how to import a pre-populated database - which there are not alot of easy solutions for. I found the best - and currently just about the ONLY - solution to be LiteHelpers CORDOVA-SQLITE-EXT (https://github.com/litehelpers/cordova-sqlite-ext)

I have added this in to my app and it is working well. I had to switch away from PhoneGap though - and use CORDOVA - but it is working for me.

Re: your problem of how to pre-populate your SQLite database - there are many options - and it depends where your data is sitting now. I have been able to convert most of the main data storage types in to SQLite.  If this issue is still something you need an answer for, then please tell us where your data is sitting now - what format?

Comment: as you can see this question is old but I did use Litehelpers but it had issues in Ios.
so I did those things myself
anyway thanks for your reply